# How to solve systems of matrix equations in Python?

Tags: python, matrix, system, equation

I have to solve system of matrix equations
such like:
variable (matrices) : X1,X2,X3,X4,X5
constants(matrices) : others

X1 = R*(A+B*X2+D*X3+D*X4+E*X5)

X2 = R_2*(A+B*X1+C*X3+D*X4+E*X5)

X3 = R_3*(A+B*X1+C*X2+D*X4+E*X5)

X4 = R_4*(A+B*X1+C*X3+D*X2+E*X5)

X5 = R_5*(A+B*X1+C*X2+D*X3+E*X4)

is there any available function or library I can use to solve this equation?
(I tried to install puLp, but I failed to install pulp; it doesn't work)

For matlab, it's too slow I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Your system is not written in a convenience way. You should **isolate** in one side the **constants** and on the other side the **variables**.
I done it:

```
+      X1 - R1*B*X2 - R1*D*X3 - R1*D*X4 - R1*E*X5 = R1*A
- R2*B*X1 +      X2 - R2*C*X3 - R2*D*X4 - R2*E*X5 = R2*A
- R3*B*X1 - R3*C*X2 +      X3 - R3*D*X4 - R3*E*X5 = R3*A
- R4*B*X1 - R4*D*X2 - R4*C*X3 +      X4 - R4*E*X5 = R4*A
- R5*B*X1 - R5*C*X2 - R5*D*X3 - R5*E*X4 +      X5 = R5*A
```

I suggest you to do an other check...

Once it's done, you can simply solve it with **numpy** as here:

```
# Import numpy
import numpy as np 

# Define each constant ...
R1 = R2 = R3 = R4 = R5 = 1
A = B = C = D = E = 1

# Define each row of the system :
# Here, because of the 'R' factor and the symetry, I found
# quite faster doing like this :
row1 = R1*np.array([1, -B, -D, -D, -E])
row2 = R2*np.array([-B,  1, -C, -D, -E])
row3 = R3*np.array([-B, -C,  1, -D, -E])
row4 = R4*np.array([-B, -D, -C,  1, -E])
row5 = R5*np.array([-B, -C, -D, -E,  1])

# Create the matrix
mat = np.array([row1, row2, row3, row4, row5])

# The diagonal is equal to 1
for i in range(len(mat)):
    mat[i,i] = 1

# Define the constant side
constant = A*np.array([R1, R2, R3, R4, R5])

# Resolve it !
res = np.linalg.solve(mat, constant)
print(res)
```